# Linking Excel to a time aggregate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure returning summaries of phone call data, one of the summaries is total call duration which can be anywhere from 1 to 100 hours.

The code returning this currently is:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(CAST(D.CallDuration AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS [Total Duration]
FROM MyTable D
```

This returns a value of `1900-01-01 02:59:21.997` for a value under 24 hours and `1900-01-02 07:51:24.997` for over 24 hours which is what I expect.

I am trying to get this into an Excel dashboard using an OLE connection but when I do, the value `1900-01-01 02:59:21.997` (visible in the formula bar) is displayed as `26:59:21` instead of `02:59:21`.

[image: Example image]

As far as I can tell this is because Excel uses `00/01/1900` for 'time' values and SQL Server uses `01/01/1900`.

Is there a way I can get this to just display normally as a time value in hours and minutes? I'd rather avoid using a string as it's got to be used as a value elsewhere.

Comment: @pnuts Sadly no, for values > 1 I need to display total hours (eg 26)

Comment: @pnuts Sorry i know it's confusing, for the value `1900-01-02 07:51` I want to display `31:51`. If possible I'd rather not use a new column as well.

Comment: I was going to suggest stripping the date off and only using the time, but it sounds like that is not what you want.  Which only leaves an option to output an invalid date from SQL server or get excel to translate dates differently.  Is that correct?

Comment: @pnuts Sorry yes this gives the correct value, but I really want to avoid more columns, I have several columns with the same problem and it would add a lot of (hopefully unnecessary) complexity for the users, I'd rather do all the hard work/spaghetti code on the server if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to subtract 1 (or 2) from the date

Excel bases it's values on a base of 12/31/1899 as 0, but SQL server uses 1/1/1900 as the epoch (0) date

also note that because of the 2/29/1900 bug, if you get up that far, you will need to subract 2 from the date (that's 1440 hours, or 60 days)

```
SELECT [Total Duration] =
    case when SUM(CAST(D.CallDuration AS FLOAT)) > 60
         then CAST(SUM(CAST(D.CallDuration AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) -2
         else CAST(SUM(CAST(D.CallDuration AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) -1
         end
FROM MyTable D
```

---

Easier solution:

```
Select SUM(CAST(D.CallDuration AS FLOAT)) as [Total Duration]
```

Formatting this value as [h]:mm should show the correct time, and you don't have to worry about epochs or leap year bugs

Comment: This doesn't quite work, the SQL query returns `1899-12-31 02:59:21` but Excel displays it as `00:00:00`.

Comment: I've added on a way that takes advantage of excel using numbers to represent dates. No conversions needed.

Comment: The second solution works perfectly, gives me `02:59:21` for under 24 hours, `1900-01-01 02:59:21` for over 24 hours. Thank you.